# How can we use recursive ls on WSL?

Tags: bash, powershell, windows-subsystem-for-linux

when doing `ls -R *.html` it does not list all the files [files inside directory foo] where as same thing works fine on pwsh.
thanks[image]

Comment: What happens if you do `ls -lahR *.html`?

Comment: That's because `ls` is not actually `ls` in pwsh - it's an alias for `Get-ChildItem`, and `Get-ChildItem` works slightly differently than `ls`

Comment: `ls -lahR *.html` also does not list .html files inside a folder

Comment: As Mathias pointed out, it’s a completely different tool. I think the output differences makes that pretty apparent. Did you try running man ls ?

Comment: Just a friendly, neighborhood reminder that questions on Stack Overflow should be regarding *"specific coding, algorithm, or language problems."* Your question would likely be better suited for [Super User](https://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux Stack](https://unix.stackexchange.com), but please be sure to familiarize yourself with those sites' rules for posting as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... where as same thing works fine on pwsh

It does, and it doesn't - `ls` in PowerShell is an alias, pointing to the `Get-ChildItem` command, and `Get-ChildItem` applies the `*.html` string argument and the `-R[ecurse]` flag in reverse order compared to `ls` - it recursively searches all files and then applies the filter, whereas `ls` tries to resolve `*.html` to one or more file system nodes in the local directory and then recurses through any that are subdirectories matching the name.

In WSL/Linux, you'll probably want to use `find` instead:

```
find . -name "*html"
```